# How to extract group categories when the category names are mixed with the data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have the following data structure. In which the category names are mixed with the product names

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'name':['Category A', 'Subcategory A.A', 'Product A', 'Product B', 'Category B', 'Product C'],'values':["", "", 1,2,"", 3]})

name                values
Category A  
Subcategory A.A 
Product A           1
Product B           2
Category B  
Product C           3
```

Every entry in the `name` column which does not have a value is a category name.

Is there any way to convert the pandas DataFrame into the following structure?

```
name        values      category
Product A   1           Category A, Subcategory A.A
Product B   2           Category A, Subcategory A.A
Product C   3           Category B
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to create a custom grouping for the category blocks and use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) to return the non-category rows + new category column:

```
# create custom grouping per category block
newgroup = df['values'].eq('') & df['values'].shift().ne('')
groups = newgroup.cumsum()

# given group g, return subframe of non-category rows + category name
def categorize(g):
    is_category = g['values'].eq('')
    category = ', '.join(g.loc[is_category, 'name']) # join category names by comma
    return g.loc[~is_category].assign(category=category) # return non-category rows with new category column

# apply custom function to each group
df.groupby(groups).apply(categorize).droplevel(0)
```

Output:

```
        name values                     category
2  Product A      1  Category A, Subcategory A.A
3  Product B      2  Category A, Subcategory A.A
5  Product C      3                   Category B
```

---

#### Details

1. Each category block starts when the current `values` is empty and previous `values` is not, so we can [generate pseudo-groups using `cumsum`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67342975/13138364). Here the groups are shown as a column just for visual reference:

   ```
   newgroup = df['values'].eq('') & df['values'].shift().ne('')
   groups = newgroup.cumsum()

   #               name  values  groups
   # 0       Category A               1
   # 1  Subcategory A.A               1
   # 2        Product A       1       1
   # 3        Product B       2       1
   # 4       Category B               2
   # 5        Product C       3       2
   ```
2. Within each group, get the category string by joining the `name` from all the category rows. Then we can return the non-category rows after we [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) the new category name:

   ```
   def categorize(g):
       is_category = g['values'].eq('')
       category = ', '.join(g.loc[is_category, 'name']) # join category rows by comma
       return g.loc[~is_category].assign(category=category) # return non-category rows with new category column
   ```
3. Pass this function to [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

   ```
   df.groupby(groups).apply(categorize).droplevel(0)

   #         name values                     category
   # 2  Product A      1  Category A, Subcategory A.A
   # 3  Product B      2  Category A, Subcategory A.A
   # 5  Product C      3                   Category B
   ```

Comment: That's amazing, thank you very much for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a very pandas-esque way to deal with this, so I've come up with a simple Python solution:

```
new_data = {'name':[], 'values': [], 'category': []}
lasts = {}
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    tp, val = row['name'].split(' ')
    if row['values'] == '':
        lasts[tp] = val
        # Reset the subcategory if a new category is encountered
        if tp == 'Category' and 'Subcategory' in lasts:
            del lasts['Subcategory']
    else:
        new_data['category'].append(', '.join(f'{k} {v}' for k, v in zip(lasts.keys(), lasts.values())))
        for k in row.index:
            new_data[k].append(row[k])
df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        name  values                     category
0  Product A       1  Category A, Subcategory A.A
1  Product B       2  Category A, Subcategory A.A
2  Product C       3                   Category B
```